# How to incorporate an xml fragment into tomcat's server.xml

Tags: xml, tomcat

I'm doing a distribution of tomcat for a many servers and in each of these servers the realm is going to be different.  I would like to have a file `/etc/tomcat/realm.xml` containing the realm for that installation and have the file `/var/lib/tomcat/conf/server.xml` import it directly.  I've tried with Xinclude without luck and I'm about to resort to `sed` to the import when running `/etc/init.d/tomcat`.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with tomcat, but will it recognize/handle a system entity?

I'm not sure what the root element of `/var/lib/tomcat/conf/server.xml` is, so I'll just use `server` in my example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE server [
<!ENTITY realm SYSTEM "/etc/tomcat/realm.xml">
]>
<server>
&realm;
</server>
```

Would something like that work?

Comment: This works perfectly but doesn't seem as robust as I would like.  I ended up using something like the result of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699666/replace-delimited-block-of-text-in-file-with-the-contents-of-another-file

Comment: Glad you got it working. Thanks for posting the link to the other question.