# Replace delimited block of text in file with the contents of another file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sed, awk

I need to write a simple script to replace a block of text in a configuration file with the contents of another file.

Let's assume with have the following simplified files:

`server.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"/>
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <!-- BEGIN realm -->
        <sometags/>
        <sometags/>
      <!-- END realm -->
      <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"/>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

`realm.xml`

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
       resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
```

I want to run a script and have `realm.xml` replace the contents between the `<!-- BEGIN realm -->` and `<!-- END realm -->` lines.  If `realm.xml` changes then whenever the script is run again it will replace the lines again with the new contents of `realm.xml`.  This is intended to be run in `/etc/init.d/tomcat` on startup of the service on multiple installations on which the realm is going to be different.

I'm not so sure how can I do this simply with `awk` or `sed`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
sed -i -ne '/<!-- BEGIN realm -->/ {p; r realm.xml' -e ':a; n; /<!-- END realm -->/ {p; b}; ba}; p' server.xml
```

Comment: Whoa... it works.  I'm trying to get a hang of the branching to really understand what's going on.

Comment: The `ba` branches to label "a" within the braces associated with the test for "BEGIN" and the `b` branches to the end when "END" is found since it's in a set of braces associated with that test. It's kind of like `if /BEGIN/ then read file; while not /END/ do skip line`.

Comment: I get a syntax error with this: `sed: -e expression #1, char 39: unexpected `}'`

Comment: @SteveBennett: The -i needs to stand alone. When collapsed (as in `-ine`), it sees the `ne` as the suffix of a backup file and failed to see the first `-e` clause which caused the error. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Works like a charm, just use double quotes if you have a variable holding the file name with the text to be read as single quotes disables shell expansion.

Comment: Dennis Williamson the suggested line (YEARS OLD) I know works as a treat, using it myself BUT can you suggest how I can do it only for the first encounter to the /BEGIN/ as there are multiple in my file and I want only the first one changed. Many Thanks

Comment: @gcclinux: In GNU `sed`: `0,/BEGIN/ {...}` should match only the first occurrence of "BEGIN".

Comment: Any tips on how to replace a block in a file (delimited with comments like this) with the contents of a variable?  Or am i best to just put it in a temp file?

Comment: @Adam: Try something like this: `sed -ne "/<\!-- BEGIN realm -->/ {s/.*/&\n$var/p" -e ':a; n; /<!-- END realm -->/ {p; b}; ba}; p'`. The first set of quotes are changed from single to double. An `s` (substitute) command replaces the `r` (read file) command. The `&` (insert match) and `\n` in the substitution replace the original `p` (print) command which gets moved to be a flag on the `s` command. `$var` represents your variable which gets expanded because of the double quotes. Note that the first exclamation point needs to be escaped if Bash history is active because of the double quotes.

Comment: note that having anything except the label following `:` or `b` has unspecified behaviour (won't work properly on BSD, for example). an actual newline (or starting a new `-e`) is required

Answer (score 5):

```
TOTAL_LINES=`cat server.xml | wc -l`
BEGIN_LINE=`grep -n -e '<!-- BEGIN realm -->' server.xml | cut -d : -f 1`
END_LINE=`grep -n -e '<!-- END realm -->' server.xml | cut -d : -f 1`
TAIL_LINES=$(($TOTAL_LINES-$END_LINE))

head -n $BEGIN_LINE server.xml > server2.xml
cat realm.xml > server2.xml
tail -n $TAIL_LINES server.xml > server2.xml
```

(OK, this does not use awk or sed... I assumed that was not an exclusive requirement :-)

Comment: It was not an exclusive requirement ;-)

Comment: Does this work?  TOTAL_LINES will have a value that includes the string "server.xml" in most versions of wc, so I suspect the arithmetic will fail.

Comment: cat realm.xml >> server2.xml && 
tail -n $TAIL_LINES server.xml >> server2.xml       # The double ">" required instead of single to avoid replace the file content.

Answer (score 4):

you can use awk

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ _[++d]=$0;next}
/BEGIN realm/{
  print
  for(i=1;i<=d;i++){ print _[i] }
  f=1;next
}
/END realm/{f=0}!f' realm.xml server.xml > temp && mv temp server.xml
```

realm.xml is passed to awk as the first file. FNR==NR means getting the records of the first file passed in and store to variable `_`.  awk will process the next file once FNR!=NR. if awk finds `/BEGIN realm/`, print the `BEGIN realm` line, then print what is stored in `_`. By setting a flag (f) to 1, the rest of the lines after `BEGIN realm` will not be printed until `/END realm/` is detected.

Comment: This seems like the right approach but it is very cryptic.  Could you provide some clues into how this works?

Comment: How would change this so that it can do the replacement inplace like "sed -i"?

Comment: you just need to redirect to temp file and rename it back.

Answer (score 3):

How about this little snippet I created:

```
sed -n \
  -e "1,/<\!-- BEGIN realm -->/ p" \
  -e"/<\!-- END realm -->/,$ p" \
  -e "/<\!-- BEGIN realm -->/ r realm.xml" \
  server.xml
```

The first commands prints the lines up to `<!-  BEGIN realm -->` the second command prints the line starting at `<!-- END realm -->` and the third commands append the text in the file 'realm.xml'.  If only I could simplify the removing of the lines between `<!-  BEGIN realm -->` and `<!-- END realm -->` without removing the marker lines it would as simple as it gets. And it can be done `inplace` with sed!!!

Comment: what about `<sometags/>` ? your sed command doesn't replace `<sometags/>`.

Comment: When I run it in my linux machine it does.  Moreover, if you run the command without the last script (-e) it gives the ``server.xml`` without all the ``<sometags/>``.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Ubuntu Precise. Inserts text but doesn't remove the <sometags/>...

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the ed command (cf. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed ):

```
cat <<-'EOF' | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ *$//' | ed -s server.xml
   H
   /BEGIN realm/i
   .
   /BEGIN realm/+1,/END realm/-1d
   .-1r realm.xml
   wq
EOF
```

Comment: should be `a` not `i` and need a blank line before `.` otherwise it does nothing useful

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same need (hence finding this question). After messing around with sed and awk for far too long, I eventually realised there's nothing wrong with using a modern, readable, understandable, widely available language like Python:

```
    python <<EOF
    import os, sys, re
    fname = 'server.xml'
    os.rename(fname, fname + '.orig')
    with open(fname + '.orig', 'r') as fin, open(fname, 'w') as fout:
        data = fin.read()

        data = re.sub(r'(<!-- BEGIN realm -->).*?(<!-- END realm -->)', 
          r'\1\n' +
          'insert whatever you want here\n' + 
          r'\2\n', data, flags=re.DOTALL)
        fout.write(data)
    EOF
```

I think sed and awk have had their day. They were useful once upon a time, but very few people can read or write either without documentary assistance these days.

(Source: the internet)

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get Dennis solution easily working on OS X (its BSD sed is slightly different). I found this other solution that I was able to make work on both Linux and OS X (I have a mixed environment). The original version on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/440013/how-to-replace-part-of-a-text-file-between-markers-with-another-text-file) works only on Linux, here I fixed it:

```
lead='^<!-- BEGIN realm -->$'
tail='^<!-- END realm -->'
sed  -e '/'"$lead"'/,/'"$tail"'/{ /'"$lead"'/{p; r realm.xml' -e' }; /'"$tail"'/p; d;} '  server.xml
```

Here a version of Dennis code that works also on OS X (using multiple lines):

```
sed -ne '/'"$lead"'/ {
 p
 r realm.xml
 :a
 n 
 /'"$tail"'/ {
  p
  b
 } 
 ba
 }
p' server.xml
```

Both these codes print the output on stdout. Use redirection or, to substitute the file inline, add the option '-i' (on linux) or '-i ""' (on BSD/OS X).

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward sed and slightly more complicated awk solutions:

```
sed '
    /<!-- END realm/,$b
    /<!-- BEGIN realm/r realm.xml
    1,//!d
' server.xml
```

- once the end line has been seen, just pass lines through
- when the begin line is seen, append the new content
- if beyond the begin line (but not the end line), delete

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { new = new $0 RS; next }
    /<!-- END realm -->/ { $0 = new $0; skip = 0 }
    !skip
    /<!-- BEGIN realm -->/ { skip = 1 }
' realm.xml server.xml
```

- `skip` starts out unset
- load the new content
- when we see the end line, prepend the new content and change state (unset `skip`)
- print line if `skip` is not set
- when begin line is seen, change state (set `skip`)

Comment: my code assumes the begin and end lines each appear precisely once