# Replacing only first block of text between dilimiters with content of file using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have been tasked with replacing the license boiler plate text in a very large number of files.  Because there is so many I'd like to script it, and ideally do it in a one-liner using `sed`.

I know from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699666/replace-delimited-block-of-text-in-file-with-the-contents-of-another-file) that I can use something like:

```
find . -type f -exec \
    sed -i -ne '/^\/\/ DOM-IGNORE-BEGIN/ {p; r /path/to/new/license.txt' \
    -e ':a; n; /^\/\/ DOM-IGNORE-END/ {p; b}; ba}; p' '{}' \;
```

which will find all the files and replace everything between `^// DOM-IGNORE-BEGIN` and `^// DOM-IGNORE-END` with the content of the replacement license file.  And that's all fine and dandy, it works like a charm.

The only problem is, some of the files contain multiple DOM-IGNORE-* blocks, so the new license replaces whatever was in those blocks too - far from ideal.

So I'd like to know how I can limit that replacement to just do it on the first block found and skip the rest.  My regex-fu is lacking in this respect.

Sample input:

```
Blah blah
blah blah blah

// DOM-IGNORE-BEGIN
foo foo
foo foo
// DOM-IGNORE-END

blah blah
blah blah

// DOM-IGNORE-BEGIN
foo foo
foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo
// DOM-IGNORE-END

blah blah
```

Expected output:

```
Blah blah
blah blah blah

// DOM-IGNORE-BEGIN
bar bar           <- 
bar bar           <- changed
// DOM-IGNORE-END

blah blah
blah blah

// DOM-IGNORE-BEGIN
foo foo           <-
foo foo foo foo   <- Not changed
foo foo foo       <-
// DOM-IGNORE-END

blah blah
```

Comment: Post input/expected output

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i -e 'x;/./{x;b};x;/DOM-IGNORE-BEGIN/,/DOM-IGNORE-END/{/DOM-IGNORE-END/!d;h;rnewLicenseFile' -e 'd}' file
```

This uses the hold space as a flag to prevent further processing of the file.

To keep the `DOM-IGNORE-BEGIN/DOM-IGNORE-END` tags use:

```
sed -i -e 'x;/./{x;b};x;/DOM-IGNORE-BEGIN/,/DOM-IGNORE-END/{/DOM-IGNORE-BEGIN/{p;rnewLicenseFile' -e '};/DOM-IGNORE-END/!d;h}' file
```

Comment: Looks like it works to me.  One thing to note: this method also replaces the DOM-IGNORE-* tags whereas the original method left those intact and only replaced what was between them. No biggie, since I can add them to the file with the replacement text easy enough, but just something to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

I would use AWK instead. Although the script below is bigger than a *sed* one-liner, I think it is easier to understand and maintain:

```
BEGIN {
    firstBlockDone = 0
    insideFirstBlock = 0
}

! firstBlockDone && /^\/\/ DOM-IGNORE-BEGIN/ {
    insideFirstBlock = 1
    print
    next
}

! firstBlockDone && /^\/\/ DOM-IGNORE-END/ {
    insideFirstBlock = 0
    firstBlockDone = 1
    print
    next
}

insideFirstBlock {
    print "bar bar"
    next
}

{
    print
}
```

Comment: I have barely scratched the surface of Awk.  I know it's a powerful system, but there's fundamentals I haven't dug into yet.  I guess I could execute that script with a hash-bang, yes? Will it edit the file in-place like `sed` does, or would I have to send it to a temporary file and then rename it? All adds complexity (minor I know, but when you consider safety tests and things like that [don't want to lose the files] it gets bigger) that I'd rather avoid...

Comment: The shebang for AWK scripts is typically `#!/usr/bin/awk -f`. It's not complicated to use; you just run the script on each file in the directory tree and if the output files look OK you replace the original files with the new ones (with `mv`). You can always make a backup of the directory tree before you begin.

Comment: Yes I know all that. There's thousands of files though, hence making sure it worked right in an automated way which I would have to to in the script that calls this scrip, and in that case I may as well write the whole thing in Perl.