# Swap two blocks of text programatically

Tags: python, bash, text, sed, ed

I have an XML file made up of multiple blocks that are very similar. Here are two:

```
    <Grid Name="EMFieldMany" GridType="Uniform">
        <Topology TopologyType="3DRectMesh" Dimensions="40 40 40 "/>
        <Attribute AttributeType="Scalar" Name="Er" Center="Node">
            <DataItem Dimensions="40 40 40 " NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
                Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/field/Er-0
            </DataItem>
        </Attribute>
        <Geometry GeometryType="VXVYVZ">
            <DataItem Name="r" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
                Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/coordinates/r
            </DataItem>
            <DataItem Name="theta" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
                Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/coordinates/theta
            </DataItem>
            <DataItem Name="z" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
                Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/coordinates/z
            </DataItem>
        </Geometry>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Name="EMFieldMany" GridType="Uniform">
        <Topology TopologyType="3DRectMesh" Dimensions="40 40 40 "/>
        <Attribute AttributeType="Scalar" Name="Er" Center="Node">
            <DataItem Dimensions="40 40 40 " NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
                Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/field/Er-1
            </DataItem>
        </Attribute>
        <Geometry GeometryType="VXVYVZ">
            <DataItem Name="r" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
                Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/coordinates/r
            </DataItem>
            <DataItem Name="theta" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
                Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/coordinates/theta
            </DataItem>
            <DataItem Name="z" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
                Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/coordinates/z
            </DataItem>
        </Geometry>
    </Grid>
```

Typically I have hundreds of similar `<Grid>` objects in a single file. Now, I want to programatically swap the positions of the `<DataItem Name="r">` and `<DataItem Name="z">` blocks in each `<Grid>` object such that the `<DataItem>`s are in the order z, theta, r. Also, for each `Dimensions=" x y z "` statement, each `Dimensions` attribute that contains three values, I want the attribute to be rewritten as `Dimensions=" z y x "`.

I don't really mind the programming language being used to do this. I'm on a Linux workstation with bash, python, perl... all the standard stuff.

EDIT: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699666/replace-delimited-block-of-text-in-file-with-the-contents-of-another-file) uses `sed` to match blocks of text, but I'm not sure how to manipulate the selected block afterwards. This [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188078/how-do-i-move-a-line-in-a-text-file-up-or-down-by-one-line) swaps single lines up and down, but I'm not sure how to generalize to blocks of text, and to make it swap blocks.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Sure. I updated my question. I'm not sure how to manipulate blocks of text with `sed`, or if it's possible to do easily.

Comment: Use proper XML-oriented tools. Dont't try to do it with string replacement, it will bite you sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention sed, I suggest this perl solution however it's better parsing xml with xml parser.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# changing input line separator
$/="</Grid>";

while ( $_=<> ) {
    s@(\s*<DataItem Name="r".*?</DataItem>)(\s*<DataItem Name="theta".*?</DataItem>)(\s*<DataItem Name="z".*?</DataItem>)@$3$2$1@s;
    s@<DataItem Dimensions="\K(\d+) (\d+) (\d+) @$3 $2 $1 @;
    print;
}
```

Or the one-liner equivalent

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/="</Grid>"}s@(\s*<DataItem Name="r".*?</DataItem>)(\s*<DataItem Name="theta".*?</DataItem>)(\s*<DataItem Name="z".*?</DataItem>)@$3$2$1@s;s@<DataItem Dimensions="\K(\d+) (\d+) (\d+) @$3 $2 $1 @;' <input.txt
```

Comment: This syntax is so simple! I think I'm gonna have to learn some Perl!

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done with **ed**:

```
g/<DataItem Name="r"/-ka\
/<DataItem Name="z"/\
-kb\
.,/\/DataItem/m'a\
+1,/\/DataItem/m'b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with replace, if you have your XML as a string :

```
#Swapping ( '\"' the slash escape the " to make it the string caracter)
XML_str = XML_str.replace("\"r","SomethingThatNeverAppearInTheXML")
XML_str = XML_str.replace("\"z","\r")
XML_str = XML_str.replace("SomethingThatNeverAppearInTheXML","\"z")
#Replacing
XML_str = XML_str.replace("x y z","z y x")
```

input

```
XML_str = """    
    <Grid Name="EMFieldMany" GridType="Uniform">
        <Topology TopologyType="3DRectMesh" Dimensions="40 40 40 "/>
        <Attribute AttributeType="Scalar" Name="Er" Center="Node">
            <DataItem Dimensions="40 40 40 " NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
                Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/field/Er-0
            </DataItem>
        </Attribute>
        <Geometry GeometryType="VXVYVZ">
            <DataItem Name="r" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
                Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/coordinates/r
            </DataItem>
            <DataItem Name="theta" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
                Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/coordinates/theta
            </DataItem>
            <DataItem Name="z" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
                Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/coordinates/z
            </DataItem>
        </Geometry>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Name="EMFieldMany" GridType="Uniform">
        <Topology TopologyType="3DRectMesh" Dimensions="40 40 40 "/>
        <Attribute AttributeType="Scalar" Name="Er" Center="Node">
            <DataItem Dimensions="40 40 40 " NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
                Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/field/Er-1
            </DataItem>
        </Attribute>
        <Geometry GeometryType="VXVYVZ">
            <DataItem Name="r" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
                Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/coordinates/r
            </DataItem>
            <DataItem Name="theta" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
                Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/coordinates/theta
            </DataItem>
            <DataItem Name="z" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
                Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/coordinates/z
            </DataItem>
        </Geometry>
    </Grid>
"""
```

output

```
<Grid Name="EMFieldMany" GridType="Uniform">
    <Topology TopologyType="3DRectMesh" Dimensions="40 40 40 "/>
    <Attribute AttributeType="Scalar" Name="Er" Center="Node">
        <DataItem Dimensions="40 40 40 " NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
            Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/field/Er-0
        </DataItem>
    </Attribute>
    <Geometry GeometryType="VXVYVZ">
        <DataItem Name="z" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
            Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/coordinates/r
        </DataItem>
        <DataItem Name="theta" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
            Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/coordinates/theta
        </DataItem>
        <DataItem Name="r" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
            Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/coordinates/z
        </DataItem>
    </Geometry>
</Grid>
<Grid Name="EMFieldMany" GridType="Uniform">
    <Topology TopologyType="3DRectMesh" Dimensions="40 40 40 "/>
    <Attribute AttributeType="Scalar" Name="Er" Center="Node">
        <DataItem Dimensions="40 40 40 " NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
            Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/field/Er-1
        </DataItem>
    </Attribute>
    <Geometry GeometryType="VXVYVZ">
        <DataItem Name="z" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
            Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/coordinates/r
        </DataItem>
        <DataItem Name="theta" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
            Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/coordinates/theta
        </DataItem>
        <DataItem Name="r" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" Format="HDF5" Endian="Big">
            Field_reflected_time_3D.hdf5:/coordinates/z
        </DataItem>
    </Geometry>
</Grid>
```

Comment: What language or shell is this?

Comment: It's python, i have some issue with the pattern reconition, but guetting there.

Comment: Oops, I think I have not been clear. Changed the names of the `<DataItem>` won't work, as typically the `r` and `z` `<DataItem>`s will have different dimensions. I really want to swap the whole `<DataItem>` blocks.

Comment: Maybe with some regex you can do something, but i think it's better to use some XLM library which i'm not familliar with, sorry. Here a tutorial is you want to look into it : http://lxml.de/tutorial.html. Best of luck !