# DON'T Keep 'Begin' and 'End' while replacing block of text with contents of another file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, scripting

I'm trying to replace an appender from a `logback.xml` file containing several other appenders with a configuration from a file containing just the desired final appender (`appender.xml`).

Using the precious help from [Replace delimited block of text in file with the contents of another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699666/replace-delimited-block-of-text-in-file-with-the-contents-of-another-file), I managed to replace the the `appender.xml` text in the `logback.xml` file.

**The trouble is:** I can't seem to alter the example to also replace the lines that begin and end the pattern to be replaced.

My logback.xml looks like:

```
<appender name="Appender1" class="some.appender.class.stuff">
      <foo1>${VAR_1}</foo1>
      (...)
      <foo2>${VAR_2}</foo2>
</appender>

<appender name="THE_APPENDER_TO_BE_REPLACED" class="FOO.appender.FOO">
      <fooX>${VAR_Xfoo}</fooX>
      (...)
      <fooY>${VAR_Yfoo}</fooY>
</appender>

<appender name="Appender3" class="some.appender.class.stuff">
      <fooA>${VAR_A}</fooA>
      (...)
      <fooB>${VAR_B}</fooB>
</appender>
```

My appender.xml looks like:

```
<appender name="THE_REPLACEMENT_APPENDER" class="BAR.appender.BAR">
      <barX>${VAR_Xbar}</barX>
      (...)
      <barY>${VAR_Ybar}</barY>
</appender>
```

What I would like to get:

```
<appender name="Appender1" class="some.appender.class.stuff">
      <foo1>${VAR_1}</foo1>
      (...)
      <foo2>${VAR_2}</foo2>
</appender>

<appender name="THE_REPLACEMENT_APPENDER" class="BAR.appender.BAR">
      <barX>${VAR_Xbar}</barX>
      (...)
      <barY>${VAR_Ybar}</barY>
</appender>

<appender name="Appender3" class="some.appender.class.stuff">
      <fooA>${VAR_A}</fooA>
      (...)
      <fooB>${VAR_B}</fooB>
</appender>
```

What I'm using:

```
CURR_XML='/path/to/logback.xml'
BULK_START='<appender name="THE_APPENDER_TO_BE_REPLACED" class="FOO.appender.FOO">'
SUBS_FILE='/path/to/appender.xml'
BULK_END='<\/appender>'

cat ${CURR_XML} | sed -ne "/${BULK_START}/ {p; r ${SUBS_FILE}" -e ":a; n; /${BULK_END}/ {p; b}; ba}; p"
```

What I'm getting:

```
<appender name="Appender1" class="some.appender.class.stuff">
      <foo1>${VAR_1}</foo1>
      (...)
      <foo2>${VAR_2}</foo2>
</appender>

<appender name="THE_APPENDER_TO_BE_REPLACED" class="FOO.appender.FOO">
<appender name="THE_REPLACEMENT_APPENDER" class="BAR.appender.BAR">
      <barX>${VAR_Xbar}</barX>
      (...)
      <barY>${VAR_Ybar}</barY>
</appender>
</appender>

<appender name="Appender3" class="some.appender.class.stuff">
      <fooA>${VAR_A}</fooA>
      (...)
      <fooB>${VAR_B}</fooB>
</appender>
```

This is the expected output to the code I'm using. But I'm trying to get rid of the `<appender FOO stuff> </appender>` old lines that get sort of doubled.

Can anyone help me replace the bulk first and last line along with the rest of the appender?

Answer (score 0):

Try omitting the `p;` after each `/${BULK_START}/ {` and `/${BULK_END}/ {`.   When using `sed -n` the `p` command is printing those lines.

Comment: Thank you! It has been working just fine.
I was trying to play arround to get the line before 'BEGIN' and after 'END' becaou se I misstook those `p;`s for the 'print from' and 'print until' markers.