# Replace PHP snippet with output of curl command

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I want to write a bash script that replaces the following PHP snippet inside my `wp-config.phg` file:

```php
/**#@+
 * Authentication unique keys and salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases! You can generate these using
 * the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}.
 *
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies.
 * This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define( 'AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here' );

/**#@-*/
```

So here's my attempt:

```
SALT=$(curl https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/)\
WP_ROOT=/var/www/html/123123
SALT_START='\/\\*\\*#@+';
SALT_END='\/\\*\\*#@-\\*\/';

sed -ne "/${SALT_START}/ {p; ${SALT}" -e ':a; n; /${SALT_END}/ {p; b}; ba}; p' ${WP-ROOT}/wp-config.php
```

But I get the following:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: extra characters after command
```

I tried to copy and modify from here:

[Replace delimited block of text in file with the contents of another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699666/replace-delimited-block-of-text-in-file-with-the-contents-of-another-file)

but with no success.

Comment: `/${SALT_START}` is missing the closing slash.

Comment: Thank you, that was a good catch . I edited the question with the additional / it says:
" extra characters after command"

Comment: Please update the question with the expected result

Comment: "I want to write a bash script that replaces the following PHP snippet" - replaces it with what? Please [edit] your question to state that and show the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is:

```
SALT=$(curl https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/)\
WP_ROOT=/var/www/html/123123
SALT_START='\/\\*\\*#@+';
SALT_END='\/\\*\\*#@-\\*\/';

sed -ne "/${SALT_START}/ {p; ${SALT}" -e ':a; n; /${SALT_END}/ {p; b}; ba}; p' ${WP-ROOT}/wp-config.php
```

If we change `sed` and `curl` to `echo ''` and then run, we see:

```
 -ne /\/\*\*#@+/ {p;  https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/WP_ROOT=/var/www/html/123123 -e :a; n; /${SALT_END}/ {p; b}; ba}; p ROOT/wp-config.php
```

This is clearly not the intended command.

There are numerous issues.

- the trailing `\` on the first line means `WP_ROOT` is not defined (the line becomes part of the `SALT=` assignment
- `${WP-ROOT}` is a typo that returns "ROOT" if the variable `WP` is unset
- some variables that you want to expand are inside single-quotes and so remain unchanged
- there are too many backslashes in `SALT_START` (and `SALT_END`)
- the behaviour of `b` and `:` sed commands is not specified if extra commands are appended (eg. BSD sed will treat the entirety of the remaining line as the label)
- `${SALT}` does not expand to a valid sed command

Simpler code is:

```
curl https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ >saltfile

SaltStart='\/\*\*#@+'
SaltEnd='\/\*\*#@-\*\/'
WProot=/var/www/html/123123

sed "
    /$SaltStart/ r saltfile
    //,/$SaltEnd/ d
" "$WProot"/wp-config.php

rm saltfile
```

- save the curl output somewhere
- if start of salt recognised, include the contents of the salt file
- delete lines from salt start to salt end inclusive
- otherwise just print the line
- once finished, delete the saltfile

The code writes to stdout. With appropriate error checking, you could add the `-i` option to sed to change the file in-place

---

Although my code above answers the question as stated, it is more likely that one would want to be able to repeat the command to load new secrets. However, with the code above the marker lines are removed and so this won't work.

Looking at the salt output from the wordpress url, we see that only define lines are generated, and so only those lines should be replaced in the config file.

If the OS/sed supports access to stdin as `/dev/stdin`, then without temporary files (or error checking!), one could do:

```
curl https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ |
sed '
    /$SaltStart/,/$SaltEnd/ ! b
    /^define/ ! b
    r /dev/stdin
    d
' "$WProot"/wp-config.php
```

- if not in the marked section, just pass line through
- if not a define, just pass line through
- else, add the contents from the curl output
- and delete the original line

This relies on a trick: `/dev/stdin` is included on every define line but the data has been consumed by the first inclusion so multiple copies do not appear on the output. (This would not be true if a "real" filename were used as sed would simply reopen and seek to the beginning each time).

Comment: reading the wordpress docs now, I see that the salt url only returns the define lines, so my code above won't work properly

Comment: Why wouldn't it? I tested it and it works. However i don't like that it creates a saltfile and then deletes it. Potentionally many clients might execute this script simultaneously and this would cause a problem. I'm trying to assign the value of the curl to a variable but it I can't make it...

Comment: @PetarTahchiev are you sure the comments shown in your question remain in the output, including the start/end marker lines? the curl output does not include them

Comment: no they don't but I don't need the comments - it's just a comment

Comment: @PetarTahchiev btw, the `saltfile` name in my first code is a placeholder. you can easily replace it, eg. linux has `mktemp` to generate unique names, or you might assume that overwriting `"$WProot"/wp-config.php.salt` is safe